# Serialization example of boost/archive/binary_woarchive.hpp and/or boost/archive/binary_wiarchive.hpp?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, boost-serialization, wofstream

I'm trying to find a good example of how to use these binary wide character versions of boost's serialization stuff.  I pieced together some code to try and get it working, but unfortunately I get bombarded with linker errors when trying to compile it.

Here's my code, in case I'm doing anything obviously wrong:

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    #include <boost/archive/binary_woarchive.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/binary_wiarchive.hpp>

    class testClass
    {
    public:
        testClass()
        {
        }
        testClass(const int intInput, const std::wstring stringInput, const float floatInput01, const float floatInput02)
        {
            ourString = stringInput;
            testInt = intInput;
            testFloat01 = floatInput01;
            testFloat02 = floatInput02;
        }
        ~testClass()
        {}

        int testInt;
        std::wstring ourString;
        float testFloat01;
        float testFloat02;

        int ReturnTestInt()
        {
            return testInt;
        }

        float RandomStuff()
        {
            float alpha01 = 26.9;
            alpha01 /= 2;
            return alpha01;
        }

    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar &testInt;
            ar &ourString;
            ar &testFloat01;
            ar &testFloat02;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<const testClass> objectStorage;


        objectStorage.push_back(testClass(1, L"test\0", 9.14f, 6.662f));
        objectStorage.push_back(testClass(2, L"temp\0", 0.29f, 3.331f));
        objectStorage.push_back(testClass(3, L"then\0", 2.47f, 8.888f));


        testClass testReceivedObject;
        std::ifstream::pos_type size;

        std::wofstream myFile;
        boost::archive::binary_woarchive outputArchive(myFile);
        myFile.open("Example.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

        if(myFile.is_open() && myFile.good())
        {
            std::cout<<"File opening successfully completed."<<std::endl;
            unsigned int storageSize = objectStorage.size();

            myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(&storageSize), (sizeof(unsigned int)));

            for(int i = 0; i < objectStorage.size(); i++)
            {
                outputArchive<<objectStorage[i];
            }
            /*
            myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&objectStorage[0]), (sizeof(testClass)));
            myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&objectStorage[1]), (sizeof(testClass)));
            myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&objectStorage[2]), (sizeof(testClass)));
        */
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"File opening NOT successfully completed."<<std::endl;
        }
        myFile.close();

        std::wifstream myFileInput;
        boost::archive::binary_wiarchive inputArchive(myFileInput);
        myFileInput.open("Example.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

        if(myFileInput.is_open() && myFileInput.good())
        {
            std::cout<<"File opening successfully completed.  Again."<<std::endl;

            std::cout<<"READ:"<<std::endl;
            size = myFileInput.tellg();
            unsigned int numberOfObjects = 0;
            myFileInput.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);            
myFileInput.read(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t *>(&numberOfObjects), sizeof(unsigned int));
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
            {
                objectStorage.resize(objectStorage.size()+1);
                inputArchive>>objectStorage[i];
                //myFileInput.read(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t *>(&objectStorage[i])/*(&testReceivedObject)*/, sizeof(testClass));
            }
            std::cout<<std::endl<<"END."<<std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"Something has gone disasterously wrong."<<std::endl;
        }
        myFileInput.close();

        for(int i = 0; i < objectStorage.size(); i++)
        {
            std::wcout<<objectStorage[i].ourString<<std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Here are the errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::~basic_binary_oprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >(void)" (??1?$basic_binary_oprimitive@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::~binary_oarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >(void)" (??1?$binary_oarchive_impl@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::~basic_binary_iprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >(void)" (??1?$basic_binary_iprimitive@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::~binary_iarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >(void)" (??1?$binary_iarchive_impl@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::basic_binary_oprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >(class std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> > &,bool)" (??0?$basic_binary_oprimitive@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAE@AAV?$basic_streambuf@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@std@@_N@Z) referenced in function "protected: __thiscall boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::binary_oarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >(class std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> > &,unsigned int)" (??0?$binary_oarchive_impl@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAE@AAV?$basic_ostream@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@std@@I@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::basic_binary_iprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >(class std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> > &,bool)" (??0?$basic_binary_iprimitive@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAE@AAV?$basic_streambuf@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@std@@_N@Z) referenced in function "protected: __thiscall boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::binary_iarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >(class std::basic_istream<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> > &,unsigned int)" (??0?$binary_iarchive_impl@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAE@AAV?$basic_istream@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@std@@I@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::init(void)" (?init@?$basic_binary_oprimitive@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAEXXZ) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::init(unsigned int)" (?init@?$binary_oarchive_impl@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAEXI@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_oarchive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive>::init(void)" (?init@?$basic_binary_oarchive@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@@archive@boost@@IAEXXZ) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::init(unsigned int)" (?init@?$binary_oarchive_impl@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAEXI@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::init(void)" (?init@?$basic_binary_iprimitive@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAEXXZ) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::init(unsigned int)" (?init@?$binary_iarchive_impl@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAEXI@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive>::init(void)" (?init@?$basic_binary_iarchive@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@@archive@boost@@IAEXXZ) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::init(unsigned int)" (?init@?$binary_iarchive_impl@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAEXI@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive>::load_override(struct boost::archive::class_name_type &,int)" (?load_override@?$basic_binary_iarchive@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@@archive@boost@@IAEXAAUclass_name_type@23@H@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::load_override<struct boost::archive::class_name_type>(struct boost::archive::class_name_type &,int)" (??$load_override@Uclass_name_type@archive@boost@@@?$binary_iarchive_impl@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAEXAAUclass_name_type@12@H@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::save(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?save@?$basic_binary_oprimitive@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >(class boost::archive::binary_woarchive &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??$save_primitive@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@save_access@archive@boost@@SAXAAVbinary_woarchive@12@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::save(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (?save@?$basic_binary_oprimitive@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAEXABV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > >(class boost::archive::binary_woarchive &,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (??$save_primitive@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@save_access@archive@boost@@SAXAAVbinary_woarchive@12@ABV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::load(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > &)" (?load@?$basic_binary_iprimitive@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IAEXAAV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl boost::archive::load_access::load_primitive<class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > >(class boost::archive::binary_wiarchive &,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > &)" (??$load_primitive@Vbinary_wiarchive@archive@boost@@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@load_access@archive@boost@@SAXAAVbinary_wiarchive@12@AAV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)
```

Advice on understanding what is wrong and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, are you actually linking to Boost.Serialization? Do narrow streams work for you? Did you build Boost yourself or use pre-built binaries?

Comment: I installed it (Boost) a while ago, I believe I used the Windows installer which apparently means they're already built?  Either way there are a lot of .lib files in the `boost_1_47_0\stage\lib` directory.  Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by narrow streams?

Comment: And the version you downloaded was built with the _exact_ version of VC++ that you're using? And you're not compiling with `/Zc:wchar_t-`? Regarding narrow streams, sorry, that was a typo; I mean, do narrow _strings_ work for you? I.e., `std::string` and `binary_oarchive` and `binary_oarchive`? Or is this definitely specific to wide characters?

Comment: `binary_oarchive` and `binary_iarchive` do work.  In fact I used the code I pasted above with a few necessary alterations for normal characters.  As for the `/Z` thing, I took a look at the project's command line section in VS2010 and `/Zc:wchar_t` is there.

Comment: I just tested locally with your code and a clean build of Boost.Serialization 1.49.0 -- I can repro the problem. I suspect this is a bug in Boost.Serialization, and I don't think Robert reads SO, so your best bet is to post your issue on the [Boost Users mailing list](http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/boost-users) (which he definitely does read).

Comment: A flaw with Boost!?  As for the 'Boost Users mailing list', I always thought mailing lists were simply for sending say, weekly news letters.  How exactly do I contact a Boost developer this way?

Comment: Just post the same thing you did here, with the title prefixed [Serialization] -- the library author (or anyone else who wants to help investigate) will reply from there. Make sure to provide very complete compiler/platform information.

Comment: May I ask why you are trying to use binary_wo(i)archive? I have a vague memory I did similar research on xml_wo(i)archive and found that the output XML has UTF-8 encoding even if we use xml_i(o)archive. Of course the binary_ archive may need the (w)_archive libraries, in which case ignore my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `boost/archive/binary_woarchive.hpp` and `boost/archive/binary_wiarchive.hpp` are redundant.

Instead `boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp` and `boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp` will work just fine even for class instances that contain wide character variables!

I hope this information helps someone.