# Store a boost::serialization::serialize'ble struct as binary onto harddisk

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I want to store the example below onto harddisk as a simple binary file. But around the net I havn't found any simple and clean example how to do it, so I'm questioning:

How to modify code below to store the struct as binary in a binary file?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/bitset.hpp>

template<size_t N>
struct Example
{
  std::string id;
  std::vector<std::bitset<N>> bits;
};

template<size_t N>
Example<N> make_example()
{
  Example<N> example;

  example.id = "some id";

  example.bits.resize(100);
}

namespace boost
{
  namespace serialization
  {
    template<typename Archive, size_t N>
    void serialize ( Archive & a
                   , Example<N> & e
                   , const unsigned int version )
    {
        a & e.id;
        a & e.bits;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  auto example = make_example<256>();

  std::ofstream ofs("filename", std::ios::binary);

  boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);

  oa << example; // shouldn't use << as oa writes a text archive
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issues are:

1. Need to return the `example` in `make_example()`. You are probably getting a compiler warning here that you ignored.
2. Need to `#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>`. Otherwise, it should not even compile.

Also, your comment `// shouldn't use << as oa writes a text archive` is not quite correct because `<<` is now overloaded for `boost::archive::binary_oarchive` so that it is streaming binary.

Therefore, the modified code should look like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/bitset.hpp>
// ADD THIS!!!
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>

template<size_t N>
struct Example
{
  std::string id;
  std::vector<std::bitset<N>> bits;
};

template<size_t N>
Example<N> make_example()
{
  Example<N> example;

  example.id = "some id";

  example.bits.resize(100);
  // ADD THIS!!!
  return(example);
}

namespace boost
{
  namespace serialization
  {
    template<typename Archive, size_t N>
    void serialize ( Archive & a
                   , Example<N> & e
                   , const unsigned int version )
    {
        a & e.id;
        a & e.bits;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  auto example = make_example<256>();

  std::ofstream ofs("filename", std::ios::binary);

  boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);

  oa << example;

  return(0);
}
```

A related example on SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439984/serialization-example-of-boost-archive-binary-woarchive-hpp-and-or-boost-archive).

---

**Update** To make the binary serialization of `std::bitset` more compact

Look at the SO answer by @6502 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251403/binary-serialization-of-stdbitset). You will then need to:

1. Split your `serialize` function into separate `load` and `save` functions. See [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) (under Tutorial::Splitting serialize into save/load) for an example.
2. In `save`, iterate over `e.bits` and use @6502's `bitset_to_bytes` function to convert **EACH** of the `e.bits[i]` to a `std::vector<unsigned char>`. You will then have a `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>` (a local variable in the `save` function). Serialize that.
3. Conversely, in `load`, unserialize to get a `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>` (again, local variable in `load`). Then, iterate over that collection and use @6502's `bitset_from_bytes<N>` function to convert **EACH** `std::vector<unsigned char>` to `e.bits[i]`.
4. Remove the `#include <boost/serialization/bitset.hpp>`, you no longer need it.

This should bring the storage of each `std::bitset<N>` from `N` to `(N+7)/8` bytes in the binary archive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed, I had some copy/paste errors in my previous post. I edited right the way you proposed. When I run the program, the genereated file _filename_ shows text-content like this (~ 25600 characters as expected):
`^@^D^H^D^H^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^G^@^@^@^@^@^@^@some id^@^@^@^@^@d^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@0`

Comment: So, this works but still it is not the expected output. The filesize is around 26K, but 256*100bit=3200byte=3,125K. The filesize is ~8 times bigger as expected.

Comment: @user1587451 indeed, but that is the binary archive. Change to text_oarchive and include the corresponding header to see the difference. The difference will be slight for your case because of the bitsets, but with the text archive there will be more text metadata.

Comment: Is there a way to shrink the size further?

Comment: @user1587451 please look at my updated answer. Try it out. I haven't, but am curious of the result. It should work. Good luck!